# DynamicParameters in .config file

Tags: castle-windsor, arguments

I'm in a situation, where I need to do something similar to the following:

```
public static class mystaticclass
{
    public static string filename { get; private set; }

    static mystaticclass()
    {
        filename = "C:\\test.test";
    }
}

public class myclass
{
    public string filename;
    public myclass(string filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(Configuration.FromXmlFile("Windsor.config"));
        container.Register(Component.For<myclass>()
            .DynamicParameters((k, d) =>
                {
                    d["filename"] = mystaticclass.filename;
                }));

        var tmp=container.Resolve<myclass>();
    }
}
```

however I'd very much like to configure this in the .config file, rather than in code.... is it possible?? ... probably not... so what would be a good alternative solution

N.B. the 'mystaticclass' is not something I'm able to change, however I'd like to be able to use mystaticclass2.filename in some configurations....

TIA

Sørn

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not possible with XML, mostly because *dynamic* parameters are... well - dynamnic and that's something that can't be expressed in XML. Your case looks pretty static, so guess if you really think that's what you want you might quite easily implement support for that via `IContributeComponentModelConstruction`

Comment: I thought so too.... for now I've solved/hached it by registering the component in Windsor.config, and then add the DynamicParameter in an installer:             if (handler.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(myclass))
                handler.AddCustomDependencyValue("filename", mystaticclass.filename);

Comment: If you're using installer anyway, why bother with XML at all?